# How to store RSA-4096 SSH key in OpenSSH's new key format

Tags: security, openssh

I seem to be not able to generate a RSA-4096 *SSH* key in *OpenSSH's* new key format with the following command:

```
$ ssh-keygen \
  -f rsa4096_key \
  -t rsa \
  -b 4096 \
  -C 'This is a test' \
  -o \
  -N ''
```

At least I get the following error message after trying to change the existing comment of the RSA-4096 *SSH* key:

```
$ ssh-keygen -cf rsa4096_key
Comments are only supported for keys stored in the new format (-o).
```

So even though I specified the `-o` flag during key generation the RSA-4096 *SSH* key seems to be written in the old *PEM* key format instead of *OpenSSH's* new key format.

N.B. For an Ed25519 *SSH* key I'm able to retroactively change its comment.

According to the manpage `SSH-KEYGEN(1)` of *OpenSSH* version `OpenSSH_7.7p1`:

> **-o** Causes ssh-keygen to save private keys using the new OpenSSH format rather than the more compatible PEM format.  The new format has increased resistance to brute-force password cracking but is not supported by versions of OpenSSH
>   prior to 6.5.  Ed25519 keys always use the new private key format.

Does someone has a solution to this problem or can tell me what I did wrong? Thanks!

**Update:** The solution proposed by @slm works for me albeit the misleading manpage and confusing console output. Basically the command:

```
$ ssh-keygen -f rsa4096_key -o -c -C 'here goes your comment'
Key now has comment 'This is a test'
The comment in your key file has been changed.
```

When run again it proves that it changed the comment to the one given on the previous command line:

```
$ ssh-keygen -f rsa4096_key -o -c -C 'Hello World!'
Key now has comment 'here goes your comment'
The comment in your key file has been changed.
```

Therefore I accepted @slm's answer.

Comment: What version of OpenSSH is this?

Comment: The version of _OpenSSH_ with which I ran the commands above is `OpenSSH_7.7p1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug in both the `-o` switches behavior as well as a documentation bug in OpenSSH.

This works for me:

```
$ ssh-keygen \
  -f rsa4096_key \
  -t rsa \
  -b 4096 \
  -C 'This is a test' \
  -o \
  -N ''

$ grep -o "This.*" rsa4096_key.pub
This is a test
```

So the comment is getting stored in the `rsa4096_key.pub` file. Since the .pub file can always be extracted from the private key, it's by definition in the private key file as well.

This SU Q&A titled: [How can I change the comment field of an RSA key (SSH)?](https://superuser.com/questions/361764/how-can-i-change-the-comment-field-of-an-rsa-key-ssh) shows some analysis around this. Also there's a comment on this SF Q&A titled: [Possible to change email address in keypair?](https://serverfault.com/questions/309171/possible-to-change-email-address-in-keypair/910959#910959).

Mainly:

> From OpenSSH 6.5 onwards, works with all key types, not just RSA1:
>
> ```
> ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/keyfilename -o -c -C "here goes your comment"
> ```
>
> - `-f`: private key file
> - `-o`: convert the private key from PEM to the new OpenSSH format
> - `-c`: change the comment in the private and public key files
> - `-C`: comment text

References

- [Output when changing comment is weird and badly documented](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/1615305)